# Python - Pip - Pywin32: Error Packages Do Not Match The Hashes The Requirements FIle

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

I have cleared the pip cache but didn't resolve the issue. I can install other modules fine too.

"ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE."

Expected sha256 b1675d82bcf6dbc96363fca747bac8bff6f6e4a447a4287ac652aa4b9adc796e

Got        20fdc50e79d65d6c2ae469ef8ad2f722164c6638f24eb0c819fe83e98137ddf9

When I look on https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#modal-close I can see the sha256 is b1675d82bcf6dbc96363fca747bac8bff6f6e4a447a4287ac652aa4b9adc796e